# How to get a new Connection from Hibernate SessionFactory after the DB restart without restarting the tomcat?

Tags: spring, hibernate

In my web application I am using hibernate & spring. The Hibernate `SessionFactory` object is being injected as a spring bean at the time of tomcat server start up. Normally it is working fine. But the problem arises when I shut down or even restart my database.

After restarting my database if I retrieve a session from Hibernate `SessionFactory` object and want to execute query i am getting `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConectionException: Could not execute query exception`.
To overcome this problem I need to restart the tomcat server. After restart it creates the new `SessionFactory` object, so I don’t get the exception.

In a situation how can I get a new fresh connection with the database, so that I don’t need to restart the server again & again.

Answer (score 1):

SessionFactory rebuild worked for me

Our app is using tomcat, hibernate(3.5.1) and Oracle db (there are actualy two instances - one is the main for the application and the second one - remote)
sometimes remote db restarts, after that exception occurs on each call

```
JDBCConnectionException:could not execute query
Caused by: SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
```

Fistly I added to configuration

```
hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery=select 1 from dual
hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow=true
hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn=true
```

but without result.

Then I tried to close sessions and recreate it.
Finally what worked for me - after this exeption 
sessionFactory recreate

```
sessionFactory.close();
sessionFactory = annotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really Spring or Hibernate related. What you need to do is to setup your JDBC connection pool to test connections before returning them to whoever needs them (e.g. Hibernate). If the pool discovers that the connection in the pool is broken, it dicards it and tries another one from the pool. If all connections in the pool are broken, the pool will try to create new ones. Everything is transparent and your application won't even notice.

Which connection pool you use? In [dbcp](/questions/tagged/dbcp) set `validationQuery` to`"SELECT 1"` nd consider setting: `testOnBorrow=true`, `testOnReturn=true` and `testWhileIdle=true`. For [c3p0](/questions/tagged/c3p0) check out the [documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing).